# Modify MongoDB object in Node app

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am fairly new to node and mongo and have a question regarding updating mongodb objects. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have a basic app that requires to register. The registration form work fine. Users are saved in in mongo based on the schema I set up. I would like a subset of users to be able to modify existing users as needed. I wrote the logic to delete a user as well to flip some Boolean values using client side jquery calling server side routes. Those work without issue. I would also like to grant the ability to modify certain fields, i.e. to correct an incorrectly spelled name.

Here is the logic for changing one of the Boolean values when users click a button: 
JQuery:

```
$('button.approveuser').click(function(e) {
    let id=$(this).parent().data('userid');
    $.post("/profile/approveuser", {id: id}, function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

Node Route:

```
app.post("/profile/approveuser", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.update({_id: req.body.id}, {$set: {active:true}}, 
      function(error, doc){
        console.log(doc, error, " updated");
        res.json({success:true});
      });
  });
```

I am working through the logic needed to display certain field for modification when a button is pushed, then update mongodb accordingly when the user saves changes to those fields. For example, if this is the Mongo schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String, 
    lastname: String,
    admin: String,
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
```

How could, on click, firstname and lastname be displayed for that _id as editable fields that could be modified?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate form for editing profile after user has registered. And separate route for editing the profile .

Node route will look like

```
app.post("/profile/approveuser", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.update({_id: req.body.id}, {$set: {"firstname":"abcd"}}, 
      function(error, doc){
        console.log(doc, error, " updated");
        res.json({success:true});
      });
  });
```